# Entity Framework 4.3 Migration bug with existing database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.3, entity-framework-migrations

I have an existing database created with EF 4.1. Then I installed EF 4.3 and enabled migration. Now I changed a name of an entity. The first line of code in the Up() method is DropForeignKey(). If I ran the migration with Update-Database it throws an exception "Could not drop constraint".

The problem is, that with ef 4.3 the foreign key naming conventions have changed. In 4.3 they look like "FK_Table_Table_Column_ID" in 4.1 like "Table_Table".

How can I change that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you able to let code-first recreate the database?  If you do this, then all the keys will be re-created using the new naming conventions.

I wrote a blog post about this and a few other things to look out for when [upgrading to Entity Framework 4.3.](http://www.appetere.com/Blogs/SteveM/April-2012/Entity-Framework-Code-First-Migrations)

Answer (score 0):

Ugly.

Have you tried installing [Entity Framework Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d) and letting it reverse engineer your database? It might better handle the existing FK name format in the generated code and help you get over this hurdle without doing something more drastic like recreating an entirely new DB and manually copying data over from old to new.